# SOAP input STRING - xml format - WSDL TEST

Tags: post, soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP Web Service with 3 string parameters in input (user,psw,strXml).the content of my strXml is a xml string format.
I do this following test : 
[image]

I have this error :

[image]

but if I test it with postman, it's OK but need the balise CDATA : 
[image]

How I can test my WS  in the first method (with the form generating by soap environment)???
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I found  the solution
I use the CustomRequestValidator and it's OK
ref : [Web service does not accept input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070642/web-service-does-not-accept-input)

thanks